# UIPickerView with UIButtons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibutton, uipickerview

I can't seem to find it anywhere, I don't know if its a pre-built object apple offer or if people custom build them.

When in an iPhone app you tap a button and then up it slides, a view which looks like a UIPickerView in visual style but has a list of buttons on it.

What is this, how could I make one? Also, on iPad, similarly, the popover view with a list of buttons. Thanks.

Comment: An example would be in the photos app on either device, tap the export button (little square with arrow in) and you see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [`UIActionSheet`](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ?